# How to parse JSON body in C# HttpPost method

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, http-post, webapi

I want to parse a JSON body and return the contents in a HttpPost method in C#.

The JSON body contains the following information:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "20"
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test() 
{
return new JsonResult(new { items = new string[] { name, age } });

}
```

I want the method to return:

```
John 20
```

Comment: To confirm, that JSON is being posted up to your `Test()` action and you need to know how to get the `name` and `age` variables from it?

Comment: @toneo yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
 public int Age {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test([FromBody ViewModel model]) 
{
return new JsonResult(new {  name= model.Name, age=model.Age } });

}
```

you don' t need async since you don't have any async methods inside of the action

Comment: To add to this, the official documentation on parameter binding is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting the question correctly, you want only to return string of **John 20** then you can directly use:

> return Ok($"{name} {age}")

Comment: The JSON body is being posted up (not in the source code) so I need a way to read/parse it. I think you need to use something like `[FromBody]` in the method.

Comment: in that case yes you can use [FromBody]. C# automatically parse it for you. you just have to create a model with the corresponding properties from post contents.